# What is the difference between IOleCommandTarget::Exec() enum options: OLECMDID_PRINT and OLECMDID_PRINT2?

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, ole, iwebbrowser2

I have a C++ application that uses the IWebBrowser2 interface to print a web page via ExecWB().

[MSDN reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that OLECMDID_PRINT or OLECMDID_PRINT2 can be passed into this method but I can't find any explanation of the difference between the two.  Normally I would assume that OLECMDID_PRINT2 is newer and therefore better but most of the examples I find other people are using OLECMDID_PRINT.